# What to do when I begin running out of storage space?

Tags: amazon-s3, hosting, storage, vps

I run a site where the content is user generated and storage space is mainly filled via images. 
Eventually my VPS, though it says it has unlimited space, will get too large and I will be limited.

So then I thought to upload the user generated images on a third party storage server, but how will I program how my website will load images from my server, and the new ones from another server, like for example Amazon S3?

And suppose I want to do a backup of all the images..... how long does it take to backup 10gb?

oh and, what about uploading all the old images onto the third party server and load them from there? how can that be coded? I mean transfer all old images on my server, to S3, then load images from s3

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is certainly a good option for storing images because:

- There is no limit on the amount of data you can store
- The images can be **accessed directly from S3** rather than via a web server

An easy way to move existing data into Amazon S3 is to use the **Amazon Command Line Interface (CLI)**. This is free software that can call the AWS API for practically any service, including S3.

As per the **[CLI documentation for S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html)**, you can use commands like these:

```
aws s3 cp file.txt s3://bucket/file.txt
aws s3 cp . s3://bucket/ --recursive
aws s3 sync folder s3://bucket/folder
```

To send individual images from your website to Amazon S3, you can use an **SDK** to add functionality to your website code. There are [SDKs available for many languages](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) including Java, .Net, PHP, Node.js, Ruby and Python.

Once the images are on Amazon S3, you can refer to them in your image tags. This means you could serve HTML from your existing web app, but include pictures from S3. You can also add security so that the pictures are private, but use a [Pre-Signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html) to display the pictures with a special URL for a limited time period.

Read the [**Amazon S3 Developer Guide**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html) for information about the capabilities of S3 and how to store and retrieve data.

The speed of data transfer (for backup or retrieval) would be limited by your own Internet bandwidth. Use an [online data transfer calculator](http://www.calctool.org/CALC/prof/computing/transfer_time) to estimate the time it would take to copy your data.